# Как задать иконку диалоговому окну в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qmessagebox, qicon

Имеется программа, использующая диалоговые окна из *PyQt5* библиотеки, а именно `QMessageBox`.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно поставить иконку данному диалоговому окну? Прилагаю фото с этим окном.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда приводите минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMessageBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Message box')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        msg = QMessageBox(self)
        msg.setWindowIcon(QIcon("im.png"))                               # <---
        msg.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        msg.setText("Вы забыли ввести переменнные.")
        buttonAceptar  = msg.addButton("Ok", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        msg.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо. Думал, что просто существует какой-то специальный метод и пример не требуется. Вы прямо действительно как бодибилдер, но в мире IT, решаете ВСЕ вопросы :D

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, а зачем в конце мы добавляем 'msg.exec_()'?

Comment: @GunTHE  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec